# How to open TIFF file created in 2001 on Mac

Tags: macos, windows, file-conversion

I have recorded CD on Mac in 2001 (TIF, EPS).

But I cannot open files from this CD on Windows.

TIF files are not in valid format (first 2 bytes neither 4D4D nor 4949). But in file I found "TIFF8BIM" at the beginging and end of file ("EPSF8BIM" for EPS).

How can I convert these files on Windows? Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Could I ask you to [add](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/325591/edit) a bit more info. For example, how are you trying to open the files (i.e. directly from the CD, or are you copying them first to your Windows computer)? Also, what software have you tried so far? Finally, do the images still have a file extension at the end of their filenames? If so, what is it?

Comment: The files were copied from CD to local disk. I try different software (a lot of viewers, Photoshop CS3). The extension for TIFF is "tif". I try to rename it (to .bin .sit) and use StuffIt Expander for Windows - no success

Comment: Ah, okay, I was going to also suggest you try the Stuffit Expander for Windows route to decompress and/or decode the files. Have you got access to a Mac? Have you tried any other systems?

Comment: It is a header of file - «Н T Sѓю Ps@  ^     * ·ф’‘·ф’ЏTIFF8BIM

Comment: Warning: StuffIt Compression Message: Unknown format

Comment: If it is not recognized as a Stuffit archive (.sit) and even Photoshop can't open a TIFF file then it is likely that the image is corrupted. I routinely open TIFF, EPS, PDF, JPG and other files formats on a PC from a Mac and the only time I have a problem is when the image is damaged. You may want to do a Google search for something that might repair a damaged TIFF file, perhaps you will have success there.

Comment: Please update your post with the info you in comments. Also: tried this https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/ ? (macOS app, but worth a try). Is `file`telling you anything, or are you now strictly confined to windows?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the files are compressed by [DiskDоubler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiskDoubler) or its equivalent. 
You can decompress it on MacOSX with [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/),
on Windows,Linux and Mac you can use [unar](https://theunarchiver.com/command-line) command line utility.
You can found DiskDoubler, for example, [here](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/2035-diskdoubler-4-x-autodoubler-dd-expand-disktester)
I restored the 1996 year archive from Pinnacle Micro 1.3 GB Magneto Optical Disks, but could not open some files. Inside these files I found EPSF8BIM, EPSFART5, TIFF8BIM, XDOCXPR3, WXDOCXPR3 at the beginning and end, and random mess between them. I installed DiskDoubler on an old G4 MacOS 9 computer and unpacked the files, after which the files began to open without problems on Mac, Linux and Windows.
In those glorious days, disk space was worth a lot of money and people tried to solve this problem by compressing files on the fly.